# Can't upload image

Tags: bug, support, images

Everytime I try to upload an image within a post on UX StackExchange and on this site (UX Meta) as well, I get an error message «Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur»

[image]

Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really have no idea, but can you try on a different browser, or even better - a different computer and tell us what result you got. I've not heard of anyone else having this issue at this very moment...